# How do I enable SSH from a wifi to a desktop connected by an Ethernet cable (Ubuntu 15.10)?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, ssh

I have a laptop and a desktop (both running linux ubuntu 15.10).  I work mainly on the desktop, but sometimes I like to be around the house with the laptop.

Right now, I have ssh working so that, when the laptop is connected via ethernet, I can work on my desktop from the laptop.

However, I cannot see the desktop at all from the wi-fi connection.

---

I believe everything--the ethernet and wifi--is routed by the same router (netgear) but I guess, now that I think about it, that probably isn't true.  How do I get access to the desktop via the wifi?

Comment: Verify that the access point is connected to the same sub-net

Comment: is this something I would change at the physical router?

Comment: Verify what you think is the case...